# Color text in eclipse console for output text from google c++ testing framework

Tags: eclipse, text, colors, console, googletest

I would like Eclipse (Helios) console to display colored text when running unit tests using [Google C++ test framework](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/).

I have tried the [Industriallogic plugin](https://groups.google.com/group/googletestframework/browse_thread/thread/45d504562f92f01b?pli=1) but it does not work with Helios.

Is there an Eclipse plugin for Google C++ test framework to get colored text output working with Helios?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Grep Console](http://marian.schedenig.name/projects/grep-console/) plugin to highlight text or line in console. 
(I don't know Goolge C++ test framework, so I don't know if you mean the same "console".)